# Order list by serach text relevance in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a list of instiutes like below:

```
    List<Institute> instituteList = new List<Institute>(){
      new Institute{Id=1, Name= "[12345] saleha ideal school"},
      new Institute{Id=2, Name= "[456987] ideal school & college"},
      new Institute{Id=3, Name= "[698745] dhaka faizul islam ideal school"},
      new Institute{Id=4, Name= "[596314] nurul haque ideal school"}
    }
```

I am trying to order this list by the relevance of a search text: `ideal` as institutes with name containing `ideal` earlier will come first.
So, after sorting the list will be following:

```
List<Institute> instituteList = new List<Institute>(){
    new Institute{Id=2, Name= "[456987] ideal school & college"},
    new Institute{Id=1, Name= "[12345] saleha ideal school"},
    new Institute{Id=4, Name= "[596314] nurul haque ideal school"}
    new Institute{Id=3, Name= "[698745] dhaka faizul islam ideal school"},
    }
```

I have tried both of the following methods:

```
instituteList = instituteList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Name.Contains("ideal")).ToList();
instituteList = instituteList.OrderBy(i => "ideal".IndexOf(i.Name)).ToList();
```

But no one is working.

Comment: Your `instituteList` initializer will not compile. Also, using `Sort` method looks more natural, rather then reassigning a list after ordering

Comment: using Sort method worked!. @PavelAnikhouski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your almost there but not exactly. Try this:

```
instituteList.Sort((a, b) => a.Name.ToLower().IndexOf(query.ToLower()).CompareTo(b.Name.ToLower().IndexOf(query.ToLower())));
```

Note: written from my cellphone, there might be typos...

Comment: instituteList.Sort((a, b) => a.Name.ToLower().IndexOf(query.ToLower()).CompareTo(b.Name.ToLower().IndexOf(query.ToLower()))); worked. @Zohar Peled

Comment: Of course, silly of me to forget the Name property... Will edit that in tomorrow

Comment: Glad to help ;-)